# Github Actions Failing

Tags: git, docker, github, yaml, github-actions

Github Actions were working in my repository till yesterday. I didnt make any changes in .github/workflows/dev.yml file or in DockerFile.

But, suddenly in recent pushes, my Github Actions fail with the error

> **Setup, Build, Publish, and Deploy**
>
> ```
> Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under
> '/home/runner/work/_actions/GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/master/setup-gcloud'.
> Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local
> action?
> ```

May I know how to fix this

This is the sample .yml file I am using.

```
name: Release to Development

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'
jobs:
  setup-build-publish-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, Publish, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Setup gcloud CLI
    - uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        version: '270.0.0'
        service_account_email: ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_EMAIL_DEV }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_AUTH_DEV }}

    # Configure docker to use the gcloud command-line tool as a credential helper
    - run: |
        # Set up docker to authenticate
        # via gcloud command-line tool.
        gcloud auth configure-docker

    # Build the Docker image
    - name: Build
      run: |
        docker build -t "$REGISTRY_HOSTNAME"/"$GKE_PROJECT"/"$IMAGE":"$GITHUB_SHA" \
          --build-arg GITHUB_SHA="$GITHUB_SHA" \
          --build-arg GITHUB_REF="$GITHUB_REF" .

    # Push the Docker image to Google Container Registry
    - name: Publish
      run: |
        docker push $REGISTRY_HOSTNAME/$GKE_PROJECT/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA

    # Set up kustomize
    - name: Set up Kustomize
      run: |
        curl -o kustomize --location https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/download/v3.1.0/kustomize_3.1.0_linux_amd64
        chmod u+x ./kustomize

    # Deploy the Docker image to the GKE cluster
    - name: Deploy
      run: |
```

Here's the snippet of error.
[image]

Comment: looks like its happening for everyone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I fixed it by changing `uses` value to

- `uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0`

Comment: Nice!  Just hit this myself.  Seems the docs are out of date: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cicd-cloud-run-github-actions

Comment: I would edit this answer to include "@v0" at the end since Google will rename their base branch to "main" sometime this year and all workflows using "@master" will break. Source: https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud#-notice

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the similar error. When I was trying to call my local workflow from steps level. Apparently GitHub actions support local workflow call from jobs level. I could not call from inside steps.

```
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [dev]

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    steps:

    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: test local call from steps # this do not work
      if: github.ref_name == 'dev'       
      uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml # this is from steps level
        with:
          devops-bucket: bucket-name
          role: iam role for the job

  dev: # this worked well
    if: github.ref_name == 'dev'
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml # this is jobs level
    with:
      devops-bucket: bucket-name
      role: iam role for the job
```

Comment: This answer is off topic as it relates to calling reusable workflows which are different from actions.

Comment: This answer is useful, though. I had a similar issue and seeing this both let me understand the difference between reusable workflows and actions, as well as informing me of the correct way to invoke reusable workflows (as their own job, not as one would invoke an action)

Answer (score 6):

There are some changes visit here for details https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud#use-google-github-actionssetup-gcloud

steps:
id: gcloud
uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master

or
steps:
id: deploy
uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@main

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wondering why this is not working anymore, check this notice: https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud#-notice

Now each action has its own repo, so you have to change the way you reference Google Cloud Platform actions in your yaml:

```
steps:
 - id: gcloud
-  uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
+  uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
```